# Javascript is ignoring the CSS inside its <div>

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page that is using JavaScript to play mp3 files. The script has its own CSS which controls the look of that specific code. I have another CSS file that controls the look of the overall page. I need this script to fall in my container `<div>` to keep my pages looking consistent. The script's CSS is correctly altering the JavaScript and the global CSS is also impacting the overall page. The only problem is that the script code ignores the CSS which places it inside the `container` and `content` divs. Hence this script shows at the bottom when it should be inside the container before my footer.

How can I get this script to still follow the CSS from the overall page so all my pages are structured the same? When I take out the script code and just type some words, the text shows up in the correct place on the website.

HTML is something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="global.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="plugin/css/style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="plugin/jquery-jplayer/jquery.jplayer.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="plugin/ttw-music-player-min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/myplaylist.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="header">
                //header code
            </div>

            <div id="nav">
                <ul>
                 //Navigation code
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="content">

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function(){

                        var description = 'Example text'

                        $('body').ttwMusicPlayer(myPlaylist, {
                        autoPlay:false,
                        description:description,
                        jPlayer:{
                            swfPath:'plugin/jquery-jplayer' 
                        }
                        });
                    });

                    </script>
            </div>

            <div id="footer">
                  Copyright 2016
            </div>          
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: post the relevant part of your css

Comment: Could you please explain this: "The script's CSS is correctly altering the javascript"? How does CSS alter JavaScript?

Comment: Your jQuery selector is targeting the body tag. Try changing $('body') to $('body #content').

Comment: Really hard to make sense out of the specific problem here. It makes no real difference where that script tag is. If something fills that container and removes it, it will be after it has already been compiled

Comment: @che-azeh What I meant to say is that the script's CSS file works as expected, meaning I can see the formatting being done to the script.

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for your reply and I have noted that. I think the problem is that there is a conflict between the two CSS files that are being linked to this page. Somehow this script ignores the CSS that I have for the 'container' <div>. I will try to post the CSS content.

Comment: use browser dev tools to inspect the specific rules that apply to any element in the page ranked in order. Then you know what you need to over write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for. Place the script tag somewhere other than the content (end of the file is usually good... or in a separate file... your choice) and attach the music player to the `#content` div:

```
<head>
    <title>My Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="global.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="plugin/css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="plugin/jquery-jplayer/jquery.jplayer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="plugin/ttw-music-player-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/myplaylist.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <!-- header code -->
        </div>
        <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <!-- Navigation code -->
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <!-- content goes here -->
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            Copyright 2016
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var description = 'Example text'

        $('#content').ttwMusicPlayer(myPlaylist, {
            autoPlay: false,
            description: description,
            jPlayer: {
                swfPath: 'plugin/jquery-jplayer'
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: that was it! Thank you very much. Moving the script outside of the container div worked. Now the script is in the right place on my website. Thanks again.